# MySQL and datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime

If I have a table with a DATETIME column I can insert dates that have a format like:

```
2015-03-25 10:10:10
2015-03-25 10:10
2015-03-25 10
2015-03-25
```

It will fill in the remainder with zeros. I can't however use

```
2015-03 
2015
```

As it will give an 'Incorrect datetime value' error. It is however possible to use these last two in a SELECT like `[..] WHERE timestamp < '2015-03'` ..

Is there a way that MySQL will fill in the remainder of datetimes with 01-01 for the month and day if omitted in datetimes or do I have to do that manually myself?

I.e. I would like to use '2015-03' in an INSERT statement, or do something like `SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2015-03', '%Y%m%dT%H%i%S')`

Answer (score 5):

As stated in [Date and Time Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

> MySQL recognizes [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `'YY-MM-DD'` format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted: Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts. For example, `'2012-12-31'`, `'2012/12/31'`, `'2012^12^31'`, and `'2012@12@31'` are equivalent.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either `'YYYYMMDD'` or `'YYMMDD'` format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example, `'20070523'` and `'070523'` are interpreted as `'2007-05-23'`, but `'071332'` is illegal (it has nonsensical month and day parts) and becomes `'0000-00-00'`.
> - As a number in either `YYYYMMDD` or `YYMMDD` format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example, `19830905` and `830905` are interpreted as `'1983-09-05'`.
>
> MySQL recognizes [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) and [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` or `'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted here, too: Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts or time parts. For example, `'2012-12-31 11:30:45'`, `'2012^12^31 11+30+45'`, `'2012/12/31 11*30*45'`, and `'2012@12@31 11^30^45'` are equivalent.
>
>   The only delimiter recognized between a date and time part and a fractional seconds part is the decimal point.
>
>   The date and time parts can be separated by `T` rather than a space. For example, `'2012-12-31 11:30:45'` `'2012-12-31T11:30:45'` are equivalent.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either `'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS'` or `'YYMMDDHHMMSS'` format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example, `'20070523091528'` and `'070523091528'` are interpreted as `'2007-05-23 09:15:28'`, but `'071122129015'` is illegal (it has a nonsensical minute part) and becomes `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`.
> - As a number in either `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` or `YYMMDDHHMMSS` format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example, `19830905132800` and `830905132800` are interpreted as `'1983-09-05 13:28:00'`.

Notably, MySQL *does not support* the incomplete formats that you wish to use.

That MySQL *happens* to accept some of the incomplete formats you've tried (apparently by padding with zeroes) is *undocumented behaviour*, quite possibly *unintended by the developers*.  It **cannot** (and **should not**) be relied upon, not least because edge cases could exist under which the behaviour breaks; or because the behaviour could be changed without warning in a future release.

If it's *absolutely necessary* to provide such incomplete temporal literals to MySQL (which it shouldn't be, as your data access layer ought to be aware of the type of values it is handling and provide them to MySQL in a supported format), you can use its [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to parse them accordingly:

> Unspecified date or time parts have a value of 0, so incompletely specified values in ***str*** produce a result with some or all parts set to 0:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('abc','abc');
>         -> '0000-00-00'
> mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('9','%m');
>         -> '0000-09-00'
> mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('9','%s');
>         -> '00:00:09'
> ```
>
> Range checking on the parts of date values is as described in [Section 11.3.1, “The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html). This means, for example, that “zero” dates or dates with part values of 0 are permitted unless the SQL mode is set to disallow such values.

So, for example, you might use:

```
STR_TO_DATE('2015-03', '%Y-%m');
```

Comment: Addendum: the reason that the incomplete formats are "supported" in the `WHERE` clause example given in the question is because those literals are parsed as mere strings; and the comparisons are performed lexicographically according to the collation of the database connection.  Whilst it is not a true comparison of temporal types (and is not sargable because indexes on the temporal columns cannot be used), it happens (due to the layout of MySQL's datetime format) that such lexicographic orderings produce the same results as genuine temporal ones.

Comment: Thanks. The only reason I was looking to 'use' these timestamps is because MySQL doesn't fault (all of) them in the first place. I was hoping not to have to write something that translates a correct ISO8601 like '2015-03' into a MySQL DATETIME format but alas.

Comment: @Lieuwe: Code to do that usually already exists in one's data access layer—so unless you're writing your own (which isn't to be recommended given the plethora of excellent libraries out there that already provide such functionality), you really oughtn't to be fiddling with such low-level implementation details.

Comment: I use C++ and I receive a datetime string  that 'usually' conforms to ISO8601 which needs to be stored in the database. I can clearly use things like strptime, std::get_time or sscanf to try and parse the string into a time structure before reassembling that into a datetime string that MySQL understands, but that is not the point. If I try to insert something not numeric into a numeric database field or perhaps a not valid character into an enum field, MySQL simply returns an error. I had hoped it would do the same with an ISO8601 timestamp without me knowing the exact format of that string.

Answer (score 0):

Try unix_timestamp()

```
SELECT like [..] WHERE unix_timestamp(timestamp) < '2015-03'
```